# Rails sort association with scope mixed ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In `CashTransaction` model I've got default scope:

```
class CashTransaction < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :cashbook

   default_scope { order(id_number: :desc) }
end
```

In one of service I use association to pull cash_transactions:

```
  def parsed_cash_transactions
    cashbook.cash_transactions.map do |cash_transaction|
      {
        position: cash_transaction.id_number,
        # ...
        # other data
      }
    end
  end
```

I use this method in other place of code to create prawn table and many other related things:

```
  def transaction_items
    @last_position = parsed_cash_transactions.last[:position]

    parsed_cash_transactions.each do |cash_transaction|
    # ...
    # some other actions
  end
```

The thing is default scope doesn't worked here - most are correct but `transaction_items` method returns me randomly mixed data (e.g. I've got position 2 at 10, 11 around 200 and so on...). How to have these `transaction_items` data sorted by `id_number` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`default_scope` is probably one of the worst part of Rails and should be avoided at all costs.*

You can just create a custom scope if you have some special ordering you do often.

```rb
scope :ordered, -> { order(id_number: :desc) }

#
cashbook.cash_transactions.ordered
```

---

* *Of course that is a bit of a hyperbole but the truth stands that `default_scope` is something you have to very wary of, because the way it works with associations and other stuff is very counter-intuitive.*

https://riptutorial.com/ruby-on-rails/example/17746/beware-of--default-scope

https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/ha6gqj/default_scope_is_evil/